# Fragmentation using YoKeyword

Tags: java, android, androidx, fragmentation

I just migrated to AndroidX on my project, I got the following error from yokeyword.fragmentation. This is my error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.macbookpro.glamz, PID: 9001
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field mActive of type Landroid/util/SparseArray; in class Landroidx/fragment/app/FragmentManagerImpl; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl' appears in /data/app/com.example.macbookpro.glamz-kkqf0yI9aDJ4LEL8p77RoA==/base.apk)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentationMagician.getActiveFragments(FragmentationMagician.java:153)
    at com.example.macbookpro.glamz.fragmentation.SupportHelper.findStackFragment(SupportHelper.java:140)
    at com.example.macbookpro.glamz.fragmentation.SupportHelper.findFragment(SupportHelper.java:115)
    at com.example.macbookpro.glamz.fragmentation.SupportActivity.findFragment(SupportActivity.java:275)
    at com.example.macbookpro.glamz.main.onCreate(main.java:105)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the dependency to the androidx version of that library?

Taken from the libraries readme:

```
// This is the use of androidx, if you are using the android.support: fragmentationx -> fragmentation
implementation 'me.yokeyword:fragmentationx:1.0.2'
```